# Data Security - Controlling Access to Fields from Trailhead

Tags: security, permissions, data, trailhead

This is the first vague challenge for me. I had to create a custom profile and a permission set. I'm getting an error of

"Challenge not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The 'Basic Account User' profile did not have the appropriate object and field-level security for the Account object"

I created both the profile and permission set, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Link to the challenge is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_beginner/data_security/data_security_fields).

[image]

Comment: Although didn't complete the exercise myself but on glancing ...Two things - 1)  In the profile, whether both of boxes ( Visible & ready only) are unselected ?  2) Did you assign permission set to the Account Manager user ?

Comment: I added a screen shot, I think I did your 2) properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking access for the Account object for the profile. Perhaps, you cloned an existing profile that did not have access to the Account object to begin with. Also, consider your Organization Wide Defaults. Remember that permission sets can only grant access (to a record) not restrict (access to) it. Keep that in mind when assigning it to a user.